# 404 Error Contact Form 7 ajax form submitting

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

The contact form does not work, and affects loading after one try. The chrome console shows the error message:

```
POST http://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/50/feedback 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
wpcf7.submit @ scripts.js?ver=5.0.3:346
(anonymous) @ scripts.js?ver=5.0.3:53
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

How to solve this issue? thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share your form data and contact form 7 version

Comment: this is my form data <p class="inp_user">[text* your-name placeholder "Your Name"]</p><p class="inp_tit">[text your-subject placeholder "Title"]</p><p class="inp_mail">[email* your-email placeholder "Email"]</p><p class="inp_ph">[text* your-phone placeholder "Phone"]</p><p class="inp_com">[textarea your-message placeholder "Comments & Questions"]</p><p>[recaptcha]</p><div class="sub_block"><span class="sub_but">[submit class:sub "SEND REQUEST"]</span></div> and contact form version is 5.0.3 and word press version is 4.9.7 @Mukesh Panchal

Comment: can you please share your online demo url as i don't get any error when i use 
above CF7 code.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue after migrating the site, re-save the **Settings -> Permalinks** in wordpress fixed it.

Comment: In most cases, this will be the solution as the url will be handled by the url mapping. For future visitors, try this first.

Comment: PERFECT! It happened just after I moved this website to production. Thanks!

Comment: Youre the god most noble sire, the god. saved me a lot of troubles

Answer (score 9):

FINALLY FIXED!!

Since I'm using nginx all the solutions doesn't worked for me.

I finally fixed that error adding the following lines to the nginx.conf (or file wich contains your server config)

`location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}`

I hope it helps to someone

Comment: Worked for me in 2021

Answer (score 0):

You Error message clearly shows that particular endpoint doesn't exists.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/50/feedback
```

What i remember, the Wordpress json API mappings has base address of

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/
```

So, try once if your url is working with this base address or not. Change url to

> http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/50/feedback

Or just check proper mappings from `http://example.com/wp-json`.

> This is not a Wordpress pre-defined endpoint and is enabled by Third
>   party plugin mainly `contact-form-7`. Make sure you have installed
>   this plugin to your wordpress.

PS : Make sure you are using valid authentication method as certain end-points won't work without that.

Comment: Check `scripts.js` file and search for `wpcf7.submit` . There you will find the URL.

Comment: Also, check if `contact-form-7` or some similar named plugin is installed or not. As this endpoint is from plugin itself.

Comment: i will try with http://example.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v2/contact-forms/50/feedback and http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/50/feedback but it will throws the same error if there any alterantive solution @Atul Sharma

Comment: You shouldn't be touching the plugin code. This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

downgraded to version 7.4.7
https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.4.7.zip

kredit to https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-json-contact-form-7-v1-contact-forms-3453-feedback-404-not-found/

thank you so much ! to vesylivskyy (@vesylivskyy).

Comment: In mycase the conflict was due to https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/